# How to create my own parameter method

Tags: c#

I saw some code from a C# Console Application that can pass a `string`-valued parameter . My question is how can I create my own parametered method?

For example, the following code will pass the parameter value to `{0}` and print the string with value of Leonel.

```
Console.Write("{0}", "Leonel");
```

How can I make a method that can pass a parameter value to `string format` and return a parameterize string?

```
public string Combine(string format, params object[] args)
{
    var parameterize = //("{0}", args) //I need something like this.
    return parameterize;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `var parameterize = string.Format("{0}", args);`. Just wrap what you already have around a `string.Format`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you're asking, but would calling `string.Format` work?

```
string str = string.Format("The value is: {0}", val);
```

That should call the same underlying function as `Console.Write` does. It returns the `string` that would otherwise be printed to the Console. Given that, you probably don't even want your `Combine` method, as `string.Format` would take its place.

Comment: Actually I have something to do inside the Combine, I just want to make it simple in my question. `string.Format()` is exist what a magic. thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the static method

```
string.Format(string str, params string[] formatters);
```

with your example:

```
public string Combine(string format, params object[] args)
{ 
    var parameterize = string.Format(format, args);
    return parameterize;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely *not* a good way to call `string.Format`. First off, arrays automatically implement `IEnumerable` (and better yet, `IEnumerable<>`), so the cast is unnecessary. Second, you call `Cast<object>()` which is also redundant, and definitely bad practice. You take an `IEnumerable<T>`, cast it to `IEnumerable`, then convert that to `IEnumerable<T>`. Third, you're calling `ToString` and thus removing a lot of `string.Format`'s functionality. And lastly, I don't understand what any of that is for, because `string.Format` already takes a string and `object[]` and returns a `string`.

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry you are right I thought string.Format has only overloads for a array of strings therefore i quickly googled object array to string array and took the first solution ;)